# EntityFramework Repositories drives from an Interface and abstract class : how to use dependency inject on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject

Ok, let me break down what I have been trying to do :

First of all here is the `abstract` generic repository of mine :

```
public abstract class Repository<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext, new() {

    private C _entities = new C();

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public void Add(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Edit(T entity) {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save() {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Also, here is an interface which I will use for my `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` repository `class` :

```
public interface IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository {

    IQueryable<AccommPropertyWebDetail> GetAll(ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);

    AccommPropertyWebDetail GetSingle(int accommPropertyWebDetailId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);
    AccommPropertyWebDetail GetSingleByAccommPropertyId(int accommPropertyId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);
}
```

And the below one is my `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` class :

```
public class AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository : Repository<AccommPropertyWebDetail, ReservationHubEntities>, IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository {

        ReservationHubEntities _entities = new ReservationHubEntities();

        public IQueryable<AccommPropertyWebDetail> GetAll(ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {

            IQueryable<AccommPropertyWebDetail> query = _entities.AccommPropertyWebDetails;
            switch (approvalstatus) {

                case ApprovalStatus.Approved:
                    query = query.Where(x => (x.AccommProperty.IsApproved == true) && (x.AccommProperty.IsLockedForView == false));
                    break;

                case ApprovalStatus.NotApproved:
                    query = query.Where(x => (x.AccommProperty.IsApproved == false) || (x.AccommProperty.IsLockedForView == true));
                    break;
            }
            return query;
        }

        public AccommPropertyWebDetail GetSingle(int accommPropertyWebDetailId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {
            var query = GetAll(approvalstatus).First(x => x.AccommPropertyWebDetailID == accommPropertyWebDetailId);
            return query;
        }

        public AccommPropertyWebDetail GetSingleByAccommPropertyId(int accommPropertyId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {
            var query = GetAll(approvalstatus).Single(x => x.AccommPropertyID == accommPropertyId);
            return query;
        }
}
```

So everything has been fine so far (according to me but I am not sure what I am missing).

The real problem I have is on the ASP.NET MVC Web application side.

Let's assume that my controller class starts as follows :

```
public AccommPropertyController(
    IAccommPropertyPictureRepository accommpropertypicturerepo) {

    _accommpropertypicturerepo = accommpropertypicturerepo;
}

private readonly IAccommPropertyPictureRepository _accommpropertypicturerepo;
```

And for dependency injection, I have the following code (I am using Ninject for Dependency Injection) :

```
/// <summary>
/// Load your modules or register your services here!
/// </summary>
/// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {

    kernel.Bind<IAccommPropertyPictureRepository>().
        To<AccommPropertyPictureRepository>();

}
```

So, where is `Repository<T, C>` abstract class supposed to fit in here?

Because, I didn't directly use `AccommPropertyPictureRepository` inside my controller and only used `IAccommPropertyPictureRepository` interface, my controller doesn't know anything about `Repository<T, C>` abstract class.

Any known ways of dealing with this annoying issue?

**UPDATE 1**

So, now after @Darin's suggestion, I have following `interface`

```
public interface IRepository<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext {

    IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Edit(T entity);
    void Save();

}
```

And my abstract class is as follows :

```
public abstract class Repository<T, C> : IRepository<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext, new() {

    private C _entities = new C();

    public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {

        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
        return query;
    }

    public void Add(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
    }

    public void Delete(T entity) {
        _entities.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
    }

    public void Edit(T entity) {
        _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Save() {
        _entities.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Can't figure the rest of it out.

**UPDATE 2**

Now I have figured something out as well. Here is `IAccommPropertyPictureRepository` interface :

```
public interface IAccommPropertyPictureRepository<T, C> : IRepository<T, C> where T : class where C : DbContext {

    IQueryable<AccommPropertyPicture> GetAll(ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);
    IQueryable<AccommPropertyPicture> GetAll(int accommPropertyId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);

    AccommPropertyPicture GetSingle(int accommPropertyPictureId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);
    AccommPropertyPicture GetSingle(Guid accommPropertyPictureGUID, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All);

}
```

and here is the `AccommPropertyPictureRepository` class :

```
public class AccommPropertyPictureRepository : Repository<AccommPropertyPicture, ReservationHubEntities>, IAccommPropertyPictureRepository<AccommPropertyPicture, ReservationHubEntities> {

    ReservationHubEntities _entities = new ReservationHubEntities();

    public IQueryable<AccommPropertyPicture> GetAll(ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {

        IQueryable<AccommPropertyPicture> query = _entities.AccommPropertyPictures;

        switch (approvalstatus) {

            case ApprovalStatus.Approved:
                query = query.Where(x => (x.AccommProperty.IsApproved == true) && (x.AccommProperty.IsLockedForView == false));
                break;

            case ApprovalStatus.NotApproved:
                query = query.Where(x => (x.AccommProperty.IsApproved == false) || (x.AccommProperty.IsLockedForView == true));
                break;

        }

        return query;
    }

    public IQueryable<AccommPropertyPicture> GetAll(int accommPropertyId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {

        var query = GetAll(approvalstatus).Where(x => x.AccommPropertyID == accommPropertyId);

        return query;
    }

    public AccommPropertyPicture GetSingle(int accommPropertyPictureId, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {

        var query = GetAll(approvalstatus).First(x => x.AccommPropertyPictureID == accommPropertyPictureId);

        return query;
    }

    public AccommPropertyPicture GetSingle(Guid accommPropertyPictureGUID, ApprovalStatus approvalstatus = ApprovalStatus.All) {

        var query = GetAll(approvalstatus).First(x => x.AccommPropertyPictureGUID == accommPropertyPictureGUID);

        return query;
    }
}
```

I have a successful build now. Should `Ninject` stuff stay unchanged? I think I only need to change some of the code from my controller constructor, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility would be to have a base `IRepository<T, C>` interface containing all the necessary operations and which will be implemented by the `Repository<T, C>` abstract class as well as by the `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` interface.

Comment: So then I will then implement my repo class with two interfaces instead of one abstract class and interface, right?

Comment: @tugberk, `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` stays unchanged: it derives from `Repository<T, C>` and implements `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository`.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. My repoClass will only have one interface but my detailed interface will have one interface too which is `Repository<T, C>`.

Comment: Will `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` derives from the abstract class? shouldn't it derive from `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` interface.

Comment: How should dependency injection work there? Any idea? Thanks for the help BTW. I couldn't think this way.

Comment: @tugberk, DI, stays unchanged. Your controller takes a `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` as constructor argument and your DI framework is configured to pass a `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` into it.

Comment: hmm, I see now. I will update my question in couple of minutes, would you care to review? I would be more than happy if you can.

Comment: Darin, can you see the updated question. I couldn't go further. When I implement the `IRepository<T, C>` to `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository`, then `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` requires all the `IRepository<T, C>` members to be implemented. It doesn't make sense to me and I am doing something wrong I guess.

Comment: @tugberk, does `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` implements `IRepository<AccommPropertyWebDetail, ReservationHubEntities>`?

Comment: Yes, it does. When I do that, `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` requires all the `IRepository<T, C>` members to be implemented which has no point because those methods should come from the `abstract` class `Repository<T, C>`. I would be happy if you can show me the complete way quickly with a code sample.

Comment: @tugberk, does `AccommPropertyWebDetailRepository` derive from `Repository<AccommPropertyWebDetail, ReservationHubEntities>` and implement `IAccommPropertyWebDetailRepository`?

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Let me show you the code now. see my updated answer.

Comment: It is working pretty great now thanks to you but I cannot figure out how not to inject ReservationHubEntities directly on my ninject registration. It is hard to fake on Unit test but it is another topic.